# SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY in Call webservice with axis

Tags: java, web-services, call, axis

I want to call web service with axis.I want to use this code. Can somebody tell me what should be the value for Call.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY?

code:

```
         try {

        String endpoint =  "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";

        Service  service = new Service();
        Call call= (Call) service.createCall();

        call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, new Boolean( true ) );
        call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit");

        call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpoint) );
        call.setOperationName(new QName("http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit","CelsiusToFahrenheit"));

        String ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {"20"} );
        System.out.println("Sent '20', got '" + ret + "'");

 } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, new Boolean( true ) );
call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit");
```

You are telling that you want to specify a soap action and that the soap action is CelsiusToFahrenheit.

The SOAP action is not manduatory and can be used to tell a Webservice which method you want to execute.
Edit :

So the value to assign depends on the specification in you wsdl. You should find a few tags named "operation name='something'" to see what operation are defined for the WS.

Try to replace

```
call.setOperationName(new QName("http://tempuri.org/CelsiusToFahrenheit","CelsiusToFahrenheit"));
```

with

```
call.setOperationName(new QName("http://tempuri.org","CelsiusToFahrenheit"));
```

Comment: Thank you and what is http://tempuri.org ? my wsdl url is http://localhost:8080/MyWebService/MyWebService/hello?wsdl- so  what should i replaced with http://tempuri.org.

Comment: I can't access the wsdl in your localhost... By the way i guess that tempuri.org is simply a namespace. I've edited the answer to show how you should set the property.

Comment: No sorry. If you still have doubts ask here and I will try to answer.

Comment: Service  service = new Service();
            Call call= (Call) service.createCall();

            call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_USE_PROPERTY, new Boolean( true ) );
            call.setProperty( Call.SOAPACTION_URI_PROPERTY, "http://IR/hello");

            call.setTargetEndpointAddress( new java.net.URL(endpoint) );
            call.setOperationName(new QName("http://IR/hello","hello"));

            String ret = (String) call.invoke( new Object[] {"John"} );
            System.out.println("Sent '20', got '" + ret + "'");

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
 at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.class$(LogFactory.java:45)
 at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
 at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)

Comment: It seems you are missing some library in your webapp. Checkout what is stuffed inside the WEB-INF folder

Comment: I just used axis-1.4 jar